# how to modify language in a child theme

Tags: language

I have purchased a theme, and have created a child theme.

In the website's sidebar is a search form, with a default placeholder text I would like to change.

The text for this placeholder is located in the parent theme's `/parent-theme/language/default.po`.

I made a copy of this file as `/child-theme/language/default.po`, and modified the text concerned, however, the modfication does not show up on the front end.

What do I need to do to alter the text generated from the parent theme's `default.po`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember doing it in practice, but from quick look at documentation there is a [`load_child_theme_textdomain()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_child_theme_textdomain) function for precisely that.

Once you use it with your copy of translation (note that timing and such, as per documentation) your changes should override parent theme's version.